# PHP break from 2 loops

Tags: php, loops, break

I have problem with break from loops.
I have code like this:

```
<?php
$return = array(...);
while(true) {
    foreach($return AS $row) {
        if($row['timer'] > 15)
            break;
    }
    sleep(2);
}
```

And I need break **while(true)**

Comment: Please don't do this. If you need to use break 2; instead of break;  http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.break.php

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can specify how many loop you want to break that way :

```
break 2;
```

So in your case :

```
while(true) {
    foreach($return AS $row) {
        if($row['timer'] > 15){
            break 2;
        }
    }
    sleep(2);
}
```

Comment: Learn something new every day. +1

Comment: Yeah Thanks! I'ts great for me

Comment: Didn't know that either. +1!

Answer (score 1):

```
$breakfromloop = false;
while(!$breakfromloop) {
    foreach($return AS $row) {
        if($row['timer'] > 15)
        {
            $breakfromloop = true;
        }
    }
    sleep(2);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
$return = array(...);
$break = false;
while(true) {
    foreach($return AS $row) {
        if($row['timer'] > 15){
            $break = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if(true === $break) break;
    sleep(2);
}
```